# Outlook: VBA code works with Visual Basic window under Developer tab, but not with Outlook Form

Tags: vba, outlook

I created the following Outlook Form. I want to send mail to a already defined address by clicking on the commandbutton1.

[image: Outlook Form]

The code in the "Show Code" window:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CreateMessage
End Sub

' --------------------------------------------------------------

Public Sub CreateMessage()
    Dim myItem As MailItem
    Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With myItem
        .To = "my mail id"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .Body = "This is a Test Mail."
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

If I open the form and click on the button, nothing happens, but if I copy the code into the *Visual Basic* window under the *Developer* tab it works.

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to give a little bit more details what exactly is happening and what "is not working" (Error msg? Code does something different than expected? Code is not triggered at all?). In your example, I see you call `CreateMail` but the name of the Sub is `CreateMessage` - is that your problem? Are you using `Option Explicit`? You should, btw, put all code that is not form related into a Module, not into the form code. Your `CreateMessage` doesn't belong to the form (but that's best practice, not your actual problem)

Comment: The thing is  that nothing happens if i run this code. As I already said, in the Visual Basic Windows under Developer, the code works. But as soon as I copy this code and put into the "Show Code" Windows which is related to the form, nothing happens. i have written the sub CreateMessage into the sub commandbutton1. I am not a developer. I know some C# Basics and Powershell that's all. Thats why I can't be more specific. Any Ideas?

Comment: @FunThomas Any Ideas?

Comment: Nope. I was even not aware that such things as Outlook Forms exists, I thought you where talking about VBA forms. Did a quick test, but coudn't get any code to be executed at all. Maybe a security setting. Sorry, but I cannot help

Comment: Thank you for your time. I really appreciate that.